# Xcode 14.2 doesn't allow me to create a storyboard project

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode 14.2 doesn't allow me to create a storyboard project. It creates a SWIFTUI project as default.

How can I create a storyboard project with Xcode 14.2?

Answer (score 5):

Click on iOS, not multi platform