# Single Views Apps in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I am pretty new with Xcode, and I was trying to follow some tutorials online and they all told me to use a "Single-View App". When I create a project, I only see App option. I searched other similar posts but none of them really helped. I do understand that Apple changed it so that after you select "App" you can select an option to use UIKit, but it doesn't show up for me.

What should I do?

I did already try to follow the tutorial with the "App" option but UIKit doesn't exist in there.

Comment: Are you sure you chose iOS as the target? If you chose a Mac app target, that would explain that it does not contain UIKit, but rather AppKit.

Comment: @ANGEL What platform did you select at the top of the New Project Assistant? You must click iOS at the top, choose the App template, click the Next button, and choose Storyboard from the Interface menu to create a UIKit project.

Comment: (@SwiftDevJournal - sorry I didn't see you comment until I posted. You should get the cred for answering this).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 14.2 doesn't allow me to create a storyboard project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347272/xcode-14-2-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-a-storyboard-project)

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. This is why tutorials should version their toolchain dependencies.

"iOS" should be the default.

Pick "App".

There **should** be an "Interface" menu that defaults to `SwiftUI`.

Select `Storyboard`.

This will use `UIKit` based templates…

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  junk project
//
//  Created by MQ Test on 11/2/23.
//

import UIKit
```

Warning: if your tutorial is really old, you might run into later problems with the storyboard templates. They should be cosmetic problems, but this should get you unblocked.